# 500 error for stripe webhook event checkout.session.completed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments, payment

I am currently working on stripe webhooks for my rails application and am encountering a problem. All events except for `checkout.session.completed` are working.
My main goal is to change the payment status `booking.paid` to `true` when the event `checkout.session.completed` happens. The stripe webhooks logs give me a 500 internal server error for the event `checkout.session.completed`. I think the problem is in my Webhook controller but I just can't figure out what's wrong. Any help would be amazing!

This is my Webhooks_controller:

```
 class WebhooksController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  def create
    payload = request.body.read
    sig_header = request.env['HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE']
    event = nil

    begin
      event = Stripe::Webhook.construct_event(
        payload, sig_header, Rails.application.credentials[:stripe][:webhook]
      )
    rescue JSON::ParserError => e
      status 400
      return
    rescue Stripe::SignatureVerificationError => e
      # Invalid signature
      puts "Signature error"
      p e
      return
    end

    # Handle the event
    case event.type
    when 'checkout.session.completed'
      # session = event.data.object
      # @booking.session.client_reference_id.paid = true
      booking = Booking.find_by(checkout_session_id: event.data.object.id)
      booking.update(paid: true)
    end

    render json: { message: 'success' }
  end
end
```

Comment: If there is a server error then the error message and the stack trace should be written into your log file or should be reported to your error tracker system. Please share the full error message and the stack trace.

Comment: @spickermann Yes I am getting this error now: Signature error
#<Stripe::SignatureVerificationError: No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload>
No template found for WebhooksController#create, rendering head :no_content
Completed 204 No Content in 0ms (Allocations: 594)

Comment: You end up in this `rescue Stripe::SignatureVerificationError` block. Likely because you didn't set up the credentials correctly. And that block simply calls `return` at the end. But, instead, you need to render some JSON error responses. That means: First fix the setup and make sure you have the correct credentials and secrets configured in your app. Then second, make sure you return useful JSON responses even when there is an error.

Answer (score 1):

I just happen to be writing the exact same feature as you so I'm glad this popped up in my queue.

From taking a quick look at the code nothing stands out much. If we know that the only event that doesn't work is `checkout.session.completed`, and that's the only one we're even processing, that narrows the problem down a bit... so here's what I did:

1. I copied your implementation into a controller in my Rails API project, then used the [Stripe CLI](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-cli?locale=en-GB) to listen for, and forward Stripe events to the new endpoint:

```bash
$ stripe listen --forward-to http://localhost:3000/webhook_events
```

2. I commented out the actual handling of the event so it was only processing the event.
3. I then used the Stripe CLI in a new terminal to trigger a `checkout.session.completed` event:

```bash
$ stripe trigger checkout.session.completed
```

4. Once I did this, my API responded with a `201` and Stripe was happy.

So after all of that, as the previous answer suggests, I think the issue lies with your updating the `Booking` model, so I have a few suggestions to make working with webhooks in general easier:

1. Ideally, your controller should respond with a `2xx` to Stripe as soon as you've verified the authenticity of the event with the Stripe gem.
2. Once you've completed that, I would immediately move the processing of the event to a background job using ActiveJob.
3. In the background job, you know that your event is valid and that the session completed successfully, so now you can start to update your `Booking` model. The arguments to the job could be as simple as just the Stripe checkout session ID.
4. Finally, splitting the responsibilities like this will make writing tests much easier (and will catch what the actual problem is!).

I hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed answer, I really appreciate it! I'm working with he stripe cli now. I get a 204 return for every event. But in the console I get an error: Signature error
#<Stripe::SignatureVerificationError: No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload>
No template found for WebhooksController#create, rendering head :no_content
Completed 204 No Content in 0ms (Allocations: 594) Do you maybe know what that means?

Comment: The validation error is a bit of red herring, I encountered this too. Luckily the template error is easy to fix -- when you eventually render the response back in the controller, you'll need either a templatable view like a JBuilder view, or you can simply use something like `render json: { state: "processed" }, status: :ok`.

Comment: where should `the render json: { state: "processed" }, status: :ok` line  go in my controller?

Comment: It should be the last line of the action in your controller

Answer (score 1):

stripe webhooks are meant to handle very little code and then pass to another route. Your Booking collection might be too big and the search being too long, the webhook crash. check this out

Comment: This was what had happened in my case! Make sure to return 200 from the webhook as quickly as possible and handle the actual logic asynchronously in the background instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue might lie in the `Booking.find_by` method. Try adding a line to inspect the value of `booking` prior to updating its status.

Answer (score 0):

> when 'checkout.session.completed'

under this use print(session)
it will show error in the console that is affecting or showing 500 error in checkout session